# Emailing based on a selection in two comboboxes in access VBA

Tags: vba, email, combobox

I am trying to have my access form email based on the click of a command button based on the selection in four different comboboxes. I can get it to work based on the selection of the first one, but the other just do not appear in the email at all. To clarify I want to be able to select 4 different people from four different comboboxes and have only one email send to all 4 people.

This is the code I have so far (I cut some code out for space but this is the jist) should I have an AND anywhere in there:

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
If Me.cmbOwner2 = "AV" Then
DoCmd.SendObject acSendForm, "frmETIC", acFormatPDF, "5047329", "", "", "Recovery Report", "Attached is the submitted Recovery Report"
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmETIC", acSaveNo
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmETIC", acNormal, , , acFormEdit, acWindowNormal
ElseIf Me.cmbOwner2 = "ENG" Then
DoCmd.SendObject acSendForm, "frmETIC", acFormatPDF, "5062222", "", "", "Recovery Report", "Attached is the submitted Recovery Report"
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmETIC", acSaveNo
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmETIC", acNormal, , , acFormEdit, acWindowNormal
ElseIf Me.cmbOwner2 = "HGR_MGRS" Then
DoCmd.SendObject acSendForm, "frmETIC", acFormatPDF, "523145", "", "", "Recovery Report", "Attached is the submitted Recovery Report"
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmETIC", acSaveNo
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmETIC", acNormal, , , acFormEdit, acWindowNormal
ElseIf Me.cmbOwner3 = "ED" Then
DoCmd.SendObject acSendForm, "frmETIC", acFormatPDF, "8623", "", "", "Recovery Report", "Attached is the submitted Recovery Report"
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmETIC", acSaveNo
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmETIC", acNormal, , , acFormEdit, acWindowNormal
ElseIf Me.cmbOwner3 = "IT" Then
DoCmd.SendObject acSendForm, "frmETIC", acFormatPDF, "72658", "", "", "Recovery Report", "Attached is the submitted Recovery Report"
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmETIC", acSaveNo
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmETIC", acNormal, , , acFormEdit, acWindowNormal
ElseIf Me.cmbOwner3 = "PS" Then
DoCmd.SendObject acSendForm, "frmETIC", acFormatPDF, "597444", "", "", "Recovery Report", "Attached is the submitted Recovery Report"
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmETIC", acSaveNo
ElseIf Me.cmbOwner4 = “LMO" Then
DoCmd.SendObject acSendForm, "frmETIC", acFormatPDF, "1326488", "", "", "Recovery Report", "Attached is the submitted Recovery Report"
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmETIC", acSaveNo
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmETIC", acNormal, , , acFormEdit, acWindowNormal
ElseIf Me.cmbOwner4 = "RVSM" Then
DoCmd.SendObject acSendForm, "frmETIC", acFormatPDF, "1354968", "", "", "Recovery Report", "Attached is the submitted Recovery Report"
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmETIC", acSaveNo
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmETIC", acNormal, , , acFormEdit, acWindowNormal
ElseIf Me.cmbOwner4 = "RII" Then
DoCmd.SendObject acSendForm, "frmETIC", acFormatPDF, "21578", "", "", "Recovery Report", "Attached is the submitted Recovery Report"
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmETIC", acSaveNo
ElseIf Me.cmbOwner5 = "LLM" Then
DoCmd.SendObject acSendForm, "frmETIC", acFormatPDF, "5032415", "", "", "Recovery Report", "Attached is the submitted Recovery Report"
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmETIC", acSaveNo
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmETIC", acNormal, , , acFormEdit, acWindowNormal
ElseIf Me.cmbOwner5 = "ENGRR" Then
DoCmd.SendObject acSendForm, "frmETIC", acFormatPDF, "86952", "", "", "Recovery Report", "Attached is the submitted Recovery Report"
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmETIC", acSaveNo
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmETIC", acNormal, , , acFormEdit, acWindowNormal
ElseIf Me.cmbOwner4 = "JAK" Then
DoCmd.SendObject acSendForm, "frmETIC", acFormatPDF, "231548", "", "", "Recovery Report", "Attached is the submitted Recovery Report"
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmETIC", acSaveNo
End If
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are using an IF statement to check wether a combobox is selected. An IF statement will process the first true state and stop, it will not keep checking the rest. You would have to create a check which boxes are selected and based on that send the email out

Comment: Could you post the rest of the code used for preparing the mails, from that i will write the anwser with the entire sub to mail

Comment: Yes I will one second its quite lengthy

Comment: Is every combobox filled with multiple people? and thus for every person you need to have an option to email?

Comment: Yes every combobox has 3 different options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an IF statement with ElseIf to check for multiple data. An IF statement stops whenever the statement is TRUE.

One of the ways you can do this is with `Select Case` as followed:

```
Dim StrEmail As String

Select Case Me.cmbOwer2
Case Is = "AV"
    If StrEmail Is Empty Then
        StrEmail = "5047329"
    Else
        StrEmail = StrEmail & ";" & "5047329"
    End If
Case Is = "ENG"
    If StrEmail Is Empty Then
        StrEmail = "5062222"
    Else
        StrEmail = StrEmail & ";" & "5062222"
    End If
Case Is = "HGR_MGRS"
    If StrEmail Is Empty Then
        StrEmail = "523145"
    Else
        StrEmail = StrEmail & ";" & "523145"
    End If
End Select

DoCmd.SendObject acSendForm, "frmETIC", acFormatPDF, StrEmail, "", "", "Recovery Report", _
"Attached is the submitted Recovery Report"
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmETIC", acSaveNo
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmETIC", acNormal, , , acFormEdit, acWindowNormal
```

You will have to repeat the `Select Case` for the other `ComboBoxes`.
The `StrEmail String`  is used to collect the people that needs to be emailed.

Comment: Ok awesome Ill try that all the Select Case statement go before the do command line correct?

Comment: Correct, you first collect all the emailadresses and then process the email sending.

Comment: I tried the code and I am getting a Type Mismatch on the StrEmail variable :/

Comment: I tried changing the data type to variant and I get an Object Required Error

Comment: Ok, the code is still good I just think then it lies with the Text being used. I'm not 100% familiar with access but the numbers for example "523145" what does it represent and how does access understand it belongs to a certain emailadress?

Comment: That is our employee number that ties as a anlias to our email address

Comment: Try to do the following: create a space with `";"` so it becomes `"; "` I checked how emails are send and this might be the cause that outlook requires a proper spacing.

Comment: I tried that and I am still getting the type mismatch error on the StrEmail

Comment: I even chaned all the email to the actual email address

Comment: I think i know the issue now, change ; into , as VBA requires , and changes it into ; if its required.

Comment: I will try to do this in acces later maybe I can figure out better what the issue is

Comment: I figured out my issue for the type mismatch error and the code ran and the email popped up like it was supposed to but the email To had StrEmail instead of the actual email address

Comment: Humm..that's strange?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87854/discussion-between-dragonsamu-and-brianna-cates).

Comment: @BriannaCates Can you tell me what the issue was :)

Comment: Yes you have to set StrEmail = " " instead of Is Empty... then it worked fine lol

Comment: My mistake yes. it should have been if IsEmpty(StrEmail) then >.<